# Automatic "yes to all" vba macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that copies over some tabs and formulas to a new excel. However, there are also some names that have to be copied over, and when they are transferred, I get a pop up, that I wish the macro to s[image]elect "Yes to all". Does anyone know how I can do so?

Comment: Instead of trying to click on a popup, why not have the code check for that condition and handle it correctly instead? If you had included the relevant part of your code, someone might be able to help.

Comment: Hi @braX, the code is extremely long so I did not include it. However, when copying over some of the formulas, these formulas also contain names. The names in the target file, should be used, therefore the macro should select Yes to All. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

And don't forget to reset it back:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: and don't forget to reset at the end: `application.DisplayAlerts = True`